# use pdo in REST_Controller php library codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, rest, pdo

I created a php web application using codeigniter using pdo driver, my settings:

```
$active_group = 'default';
$active_record = TRUE;

$db['default']['hostname'] = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testDB';
$db['default']['username'] = 'root';
$db['default']['password'] = '';
$db['default']['database'] = 'testDB';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'pdo';
...
```

Everything works fine. Now, I want to create a REST API for the same so, I decided to use REST_Controller ([Codeignitor REST Server](https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-restserver)). Now, when I use the above settings, it doesn't work. The database queries inside the library don't work, instead return empty result when I debugged. Setting the database driver to mysql works however. Since, my REST server will use the queries I have already written in PDO, I want to use PDO here also, but it is not working. I am using X-API-KEY method. Can someone help me out with this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in codeignitor 2.x branch and is fixed in 3.x devel branch.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same probs with CodeIgniter 2 & REST_Controller. Perhaps we can work on a hotfix? Any idea what causes this bug?

**Edit: Fixed it!**

You need to replace the following folders/files with the latest CI3 version of these folders/files (https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter).

- /system/database/
- /application/config/database.php
- /application/config/contstans.php

Et voila, works.

Note: 3.0 is not released yet, however I don't see any PDO / database related issues listed on Github. Based on this I assume it's safe to update these files.

Comment: I saw a github issue for the same, don't remember the link, anyways codeignitor 3.x has only one open issue and very much safe for production. The main reason for it not getting released is ellislab is looking for a new owner for codeignitor.